# AngularJS - Toggle class on specific button using ng-class directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('vlcObject', function ($compile, $rootScope, $timeout, $window) {
var vlcPlayerId = '';
var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

scope.muteClass = 'fa fa-volume-on';

<button id=mute_uniqId ng-click="doMute(uniqId)"><i ng-class="muteClass"></i></button>

scope.doMute = function(uniqId){
    var vlc = scope.getVLC("vlc");
     if (vlc && vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
        vlc.audio.toggleMute();
        scope.controlClass = 'fa fa-volume-off';
    }else{
        scope.controlClass = 'fa fa-volume-on';
    }
}

};
return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: linker
};
```

});

If there are multiple buttons, toggling class is applied to every button.

1. How do I toggle class to button which is clicked and not every other button using ng-class directive ? i.e. scope.controlClass should be applied only to button which is clicked.

Comment: Please post your doMute function as well

Comment: (1) Aren't you missing the `$` in `$scope`? (2) If you want `muteClass` to be replaced within the <i...>` element, wrap it as `"{{muteClass}}"`.

Comment: @UmairFarooq, the function is already posted. Check scope.doMute.

Comment: @FDavidov, could you post this as an answer relevant to above code ? Also this is a directive, so avoid using $scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Use $event**

You can pass $event to the doMute function.

So the doMute function become:

```
scope.nomuteClass = 'fa fa-volume-on';
scope.muteClass = 'fa fa-volume-off';
scope.doMute = function(uniqId, event){
        var vlc = scope.getVLC("vlc");
         if (vlc && vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
            vlc.audio.toggleMute();
            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass(scope.muteClass).addClass(scope.nomuteClass);
        } else{
            angular.element(event.target).children().removeClass(scope.nomuteClass).addClass(scope.muteClass);
        }
}
```

And your element:

```
<button id=mute_uniqId ng-click="doMute(uniqId, $event)"><i></i></button>
```

Comment: event.target.children is not a function

Comment: Fixed :) Edited. I just forgot to convert target to angular element.

Comment: I have to pass default class in `<i ng-class="muteClass"></i>` OR how do I load button with class before toggle ?

Comment: Well you still can put the default class and it will work.

Comment: Did below but still not working.
`scope.muteClass = 'fa fa-volume-off';
<button id=mute_uniqId ng-click="doMute(uniqId, $event)"><i ng-class="muteClass"></i></button>

scope.doMute = function (vlcPlayer,event) {
 var vlc = scope.getVLC("vlc");
         if (vlc && vlc.playlist.isPlaying) {
            vlc.audio.toggleMute();
            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-volume-off');
        } else{
            angular.element(event.target).children().addClass('fa fa-volume-on');
        }
}` Also I see tag as `<i class="fa fa-volume-off fa-volume-on"></i>`

Comment: Just add removeClass before adding the new class. Edited.

Comment: The issue is, `toggleClass` is applied to  that button. But suppose if I click on stop button, how do I change class from pause to play ? For ex `<button id=stop_uniqId ng-click="doStop(uniqId,event)"><i class="fa fa-stop"><</i></button>` when clicked, class should be applied to play-pause button

Answer (score 0):

Here is my comment as an answer + a response to your feedback:

1) In your JS code, you should use:

```
$scope.doMute = function(...) {...} ;
```

and:

```
$scope.muteClass = 'fa fa-volume-on';
```

if you want Angular to perform bi-directional binding. Angular's object is `$scope` and not `scope`, and **NO**, `scope` is **NOT** a directive.

Last, your HTML should be:

```
<button id=mute_uniqId ng-click="doMute(uniqId)"><i ng-class="{{muteClass}}"></i></button>
```